# Chart.js animate doughnut on update

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for the best way to update a doughnut chart in [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/), without it animating from scratch, but rather from the position is was in. For example, we're looking at a live pie chart showing the ages of people in a room, but when we update the chart, so every 5 seconds, we need to shuffle.

Looks and works perfectly without animation, but we're keen to get the easing there, etc.